# Why am I getting UNAUTHORIZED error when calling an HTTP function in Google Cloud?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have deployed a function in Google Cloud which creates new users when called, however its failing and returns **UNAUTHORIZED** error which is supposed to indicate that the user's token is not valid, however, the user that I am using to login is set as "Owner" in Cloud Function.

I have removed the "*Allow unauthenticated*" so now only the authenticated users(admins) can execute this function.

**Package.json engine and dependencies:**

```
  ...
  "engines": {
  "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.4.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.0"
  }
  ...
```

**My Firebase**(installed with npm install -g firebase-tools) **version**:

```
firebase --version : 8.0.3 //tried the latest one 8.1.0 but it fails when I deploy so downgraded to 8.0.3
```

**Here is the function(reduced to minimal code):**

```
exports.createUser = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        if (!data.email.endsWith('@admin.com')) {
            throw "Wrong email domain";
        }
        if (!context.auth) {
            throw new UnauthenticatedError('The user is not authenticated. Only authenticated Admin users can create new users.');
        }

        const callerUid = context.auth.uid;
        const callerUserRecord = await admin.auth().getUser(callerUid);
        if (!callerUserRecord.customClaims.admin) {
            throw new NotAnAdminError('Only Admin users can create new users.');
        }
        const role = data.role;
        if (!roleIsValid(role)) {
            throw new InvalidRoleError('The "' + role + '" role is not a valid role');
        }

        const userCreationRequest = {
            userDetails: data,
            status: 'Pending',
            createdBy: callerUid,
            createdOn: FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        }

        const userCreationRequestRef = await admin.firestore().collection("userCreationRequests").add(userCreationRequest);

        const newUser = {
            email: data.email,
            emailVerified: false,
            password: data.password,
            disabled: false
        }

        const userRecord = await admin
            .auth()
            .createUser(newUser);

        const userId = userRecord.uid;

        const claims = {};
        claims[role] = true;

        await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userId, claims);

            await admin.firestore().collection("Collection").doc(userId).collection('private').doc('priv').set({
                act: 0,
                acc: "",
                alt: "",
                lat: "",
                long: "",
                speed: "",
                altAcc: "",
                course: "",
                courseAcc: "",
                time: "",
                devID: ""
            });

        await userCreationRequestRef.update({ status: 'Treated' });
        return { result: 'The new user has been successfully created.' };
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.type === 'UnauthenticatedError') {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unauthenticated', error.message);
        }
    }
});
```

**And below you can see the way I call it from my app:**

```
_sendHttpCreateUser = () => {
    var createUser = firebase.app().functions('europe-west1').httpsCallable('createUser');

    const { newUser_email, newUser_password, name, surname, role, phone, personalID, street, city } = this.state;

        var user = {
            email: newUser_email,
            password: newUser_password,
            nam: name,
            personalID: personalID,
            surn: surname,
            tel: phone,
            role: role
        };

    createUser(user)
        .then(function (resp) {
            console.log(resp.data.result);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            var code = error.code;
            var message = error.message;
        });
}
```

As I said the only error I am getting is UNAUTHORIZED and I googled it and found that means if user doesn't provide the correct token then it throws that error however I am providing since the user that I am using to log in is registered in the google cloud console as admin. Do I need to set that user as admin somewhere else?
Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: What version of the Firebase CLI are you using?  Run `firebase --version`.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson , I am running Firebase 8.0.2

Comment: @DougStevenson Should I update as it prompts: `Update available 8.0.2 → 8.1.0`

Comment: It's always good to update, but I'm not sure that's going to resolve the issue.  If you do update, try deleting the function and redeploying with the new CLI.

Comment: You might want to debug your exception handling as well. Be sure you know what error your function is actually throwing, if any. Add debug logging.

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated and now when I deploy the function it throws an error: `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ deploy: firebase deploy --only`...

Comment: @DougStevenson How can I actually run debugging in Cloud Functions?

Comment: Add debug logging and check the logs in the console.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am trying to run it with unauthorization -  allowed for all users and now it failing with INTERNAL error.

Comment: @DougStevenson removed the All Users permission, now again it fails with UNAUTHORIZED.